# want to upload a file to s3 using apache airflow [ DAG ] file

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

i want to make a DAG file (apache airflow) for uploading a rar file to s3 bucket any one tried.? plz suggest ,

and i tried these things on my DAG file but there is showing some error

```
from airflow.operators import SimpleHttpOperator, HttpSensor,   , EmailOperator, S3KeySensor
```

The error is

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py:439: DeprecationWarning: Importing 'SimpleHttpOperator' directly from 'airflow.operators' has been deprecated. Please import from 'airflow.operators.[operator_module]' instead. Support for direct imports will be dropped entirely in Airflow 2.0.
>
> DeprecationWarning)
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py:439: DeprecationWarning: Importing 'HttpSensor' directly from 'airflow.operators' has been deprecated. Please import from 'airflow.operators.[operator_module]' instead. Support for direct imports will be dropped entirely in Airflow 2.0.
>
> DeprecationWarning)
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py:439: DeprecationWarning: Importing 'EmailOperator' directly from 'airflow.operators' has been deprecated. Please import from 'airflow.operators.[operator_module]' instead. Support for direct imports will be dropped entirely in Airflow 2.0.

how to solve this issue.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a warning, not an error. A `DeprecationWarning` usually hints that something you're doing will work now, but may break in future versions. If your task is failing, ignore these messages and look for a proper error.

Code for operators have always been located under `airflow.operators.[operator_module]`, but it was also made available under `airflow.operators` directly for convenience. For example, `SimpleHttpOperator` is defined in https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.9/airflow/operators/http_operator.py, so importing it from `airflow.operators.http_operator` will definitely work. However, importing it from `airflow.operators` will also work due to the code that currently exists in [https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.9/airflow/operators/**init**.py#L97-L99](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.9/airflow/operators/__init__.py#L97-L99), at least for now in your current version of Airflow. Basically, you can address these warnings by updating your imports to the following:

```
from airflow.operators.http_operator import SimpleHttpOperator
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
from airflow.sensors.http_sensor import HttpSensor
from airflow.sensors.s3_key_sensor import S3KeySensor
```

Just heads up, currently only on the master branch, not yet in any released version, some of the third party operators and sensors have also been moved again. For example, `S3KeySensor` will be found under `providers.amazon.aws.sensors.s3_key.py`. As expected, importing from the "old" path will get you a similar deprecation message, https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/97a429f9d0cf740c5698060ad55f11e93cb57b55/airflow/sensors/s3_key_sensor.py#L25-L28.